# ProgressBar using drawable xml and styles

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-styles

I am currently using an xml file as the drawable for my `ProgressBar`, and I want to be able to let the user have a choice of theme. For this I want to be able to change the stroke around the `ProgressBar` depending on what they select. Do I need to create a new drawable xml for each different theme or can I use `styles` to change the stroke color. The stroke is the only thing I want to change so it seems a bit silly to need a whole new drawable xml. Are there any parameters I can put in my `styles` file to do this?

Drawable xml for my `ProgressBar`:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <corners android:radius="5dip" />
        <stroke android:color="#ffffffff"
                android:width="1dp" />
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#009d9e9d"
            android:centerColor="#005a5d5a"
            android:centerY="0.75"
            android:endColor="#00747674"
            android:angle="270"
        />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="5dip" />
            <stroke android:color="#ffffffff"
                android:width="1dp" />
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#80ffd300"
                android:centerColor="#80ffb600"
                android:centerY="0.75"
                android:endColor="#a0ffcb00"
                android:angle="270"
            />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
<item
    android:id="@android:id/progress"
>
<clip>
    <shape>
        <corners
            android:radius="5dip" />
        <stroke android:color="#ffffffff"
            android:width="1dp" />    
        <gradient
            android:startColor="@color/orangelight"
            android:endColor="@color/orangedark"
            android:angle="270" />
    </shape>
</clip>
</item>

</layer-list>
```